# How Can I Paste image from desktop to MS Paint by using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know how to copy the image from desktop and paste it in MS paint using VBA EXCEL MACRO. please help in completing the code below.

Sub PasteImage()

```
Shell = ("MSPAINT")

Dim ImagePath As String
Dim PAINT As String

    PAINT = "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe"   
    ImagePath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\5841762-image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this

```
Shell PAINT & " """ & ImagePath & """"
```